# pip install: trying to install multiple version of same package from private pypi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I've a private pypi, and keep uploading new package `framework` to that registry.

I want to install the latest package in a virtualenv.

#### Command used:

```
pip install -i https://user:pass@registry framework
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Collecting framework:
   ... downloads many versions

ERROR: Cannot install framework==0.25.13, framework==0.25.14 and framework==0.26.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    framework 0.26.0 depends on toolz<0.12.0 and >=0.11.1
    framework 0.25.14 depends on toolz<0.12.0 and >=0.11.1
    framework 0.25.13 depends on toolz<0.12.0 and >=0.11.1

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

I want only the latest version to be downloaded. I cannot hard-code version like `framework==0.26.0` while pip install because this command is to be used in script and I may need to modify the script everytime a new `framework` get uploaded.

**pip version: pip 21.1.2**

Comment: you can use a conda environment or pipenv to solve this problem.

Comment: The package you are trying to install has incorrect dependencies.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate your comments? Thank you

Comment: You are trying to install multiple versions of the same package at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for this problem was using `--extra-index-url` instead of `-i`

#### Command to use

```
pip install --extra-index-url https://user:pass@registry framework
```